# How to set the global variable from one jQuery function and access it to another function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can I declare,set and access global variable from one function to another?

```js
var testvar;
$(document).ready(function(){
test1();
});

function test1(){
  return testvar;
}

function test2(){
  var a = "Hellow World";
  testvar = a;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The code above was just my sample to make it easy to understand on what I am trying to do. This is just for educational purposes. I just want to get the result in that way. Or is there a way to set a Global variable within a function and use it to another function outside that function?

Comment: function test2(){
  var a = "Hellow World";
  `var testvar = a;`
}

Comment: Well, the issue in your example is that `test2` is never called. If you'd call it and log `test1`'s return value, you'd see that what you have works.

Comment: Luckily you don't have to, jQuery has `$.data`

Comment: Misspelled `testvar` when you declared it: `var tsetvar;`

Comment: @CatalinSterian that is not going to set the global variable it will create a new variable in the scope of test2()

Comment: how can I use $.data? sorry dude, I'm new on jQuery.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/uwzapwrk/ 1) miss spell of testvar 2)  test1() is not callinh test2() so the var remains unchanged.. everithing else works

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/7yf8e5bf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## What do to?

Creating variables in the Global scope is *very* bad practice. You shouldn't do it because it can cause conflicts *especially* in future JavaScript versions.

You can run the functions from a scope or object, try:

```
var shared = {};

$(document).ready(function () {
    test1.call(shared);//undefined
    test2.call(shared);
    test1.call(shared);//foo
});

function test1 () {
    alert(this.testvar);
}

function test2 () {
    var a = 'foo';
    this.testvar = a;
}
```

### How it works

In simple terms, this will store all the variables in the object (`shared`). You can declared a *"shared variable"* by using `this.` instead of `var`. By using `.call()` we can choose to run the function in the scope of the object. I'm not the best at explaining, learn more [here](http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/)

## [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qfz5dn75/)

Answer (score 0):

Global Variables are always accessible from everywhere. But this might help you understand it better:

```
var testvar;
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log(testvar); // outputs: undefined
    test2();
    console.log(testvar); // outputs Hello World
    console.log(test1()); //outputs Hello World
});

function test1(){
  return testvar;
}

function test2(){
  var a = "Hellow World";
  testvar = a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var testvar;
$(document).ready(function(){
  test1();
});

function test1(){
  return test2();
}

function test2(){
 var a = "Hellow World";
  testvar = a;
}

console.log(testvar);
```

test2() is not called. It needs to be called in order to redeclare the variable

https://jsfiddle.net/uwzapwrk/

Answer (score 0):

I use this method and it works for me

```
function somefunctionname(){
    // Some action
anotherfunctionname(put_your_value);
}

function anotherfunctionname(put_parameter_as_you_want){
var some_var = put_parameter_as_you_want;
    // Some action with your var
}
```

This method work after somefunctionname() was execute and you can execute the anotherfunctionname() with variable was store on somefunctionname()