# JS How to set a global var or pass a var from a function to another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this click function:

```
$(document).on('click', 'path[data-availability="Available"]', function () {
   var path_str = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(this);
   get_data_mapping_for_id(this); //see below for this code
});
```

Which loads an svg path in a modal. When the user clicks on the button inside the modal, we need to log the user into the account first before the action can be completed. Once logged in, the user is brought back to the page where the modal originated. The goal is to re-open the modal after the user logs in.

I need this var 'path_str' from the above to be available in another function, example below:

```
if (i==1){
   alert(path_str)
}
```

I tried declaring var path_str = ''; "outside of any block or function, inside the global scope" and based on this quote: "Normally, when you create a variable inside a function, that variable is local, and can only be used inside that function. To create a global variable inside a function, you can use the global keyword." I also tried the following, but it crashes the svg modal:

```
$(document).on('click', 'path[data-availability="Available"]', function () {
   global path_str
   path_str = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(this);   
   
   get_data_mapping_for_id(this);
});
```

I also tried manually placing a random svg 'path' value to the var path and it works, naturally, but...:

```
if (i==1){
   var path = '<path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" data-map-id="1" style="fill: rgb(240, 173, 78);" class="st3" d="M345.1,302.4V276c0-3.5,2.8-6.3,6.3-6.3h20.3v32.7H345.1z" data-availability="Available"/>';
   var path_str = $(path).attr('data-map-id');
   alert(path_str)
}
```

**Is there a way to pass the 'path_str' value from the click function to another function?**
This https://jsfiddle.net/qfz5dn75/ found here: [How to set the global variable from one jQuery function and access it to another function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29859871/how-to-set-the-global-variable-from-one-jquery-function-and-access-it-to-another)

comes very close to answering my question, but I don't know how to implement it across my two functions please help + thanks in advance!

```
// here is the get_data_mapping_for_id()
function get_data_mapping_for_id(path) {
      let id = $(path).attr('data-map-id');

      Swal.fire({
        title: 'Loading data...',
        willOpen: function () {
          $('path[data-map-id="' + id + '"]').addClass("highlight-path")

          Swal.showLoading();
          $.get(endPoint, { action: 'get_data_mapping_for_id', id }, function (data) {
            Swal.hideLoading();
            jsonResp = JSON.parse(data);
            const table = jsonToHTMLTable(jsonResp, $(path));
            Swal.update({
              title: jsonResp.title,
              html: table,
              confirmButtonText: 'Close'
            });
          });
        },
        willClose: function () {
          $('path[data-map-id="' + id + '"]').removeClass("highlight-path");
        }
      });
}
```

Comment: You can always use the `window` as a global object, like `window.str_path = 'something'`. or you can use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` if you want to persist across pages.

Comment: If you type code use triple backticks not single if your code has more than one line.

Comment: Please clarify what that "login" actually entails. Is the user staying on the current page and everything login-related is handled via JavaScript? Or does _"the user is brought back to the page where the modal originated"_ mean the page will actually get reloaded? If the latter, then of course no JS variables will "survive" that, not even global ones. You should store the information into sessionStorage then.

Comment: @jcubic ok thanks! @IT goldman this really works well. @CBroe your correct. Thanks everyone. quick question, now that I can retrieve the 'path' var when the user clicked the svg map, how would I repeat/ mimic the click action for the same svg path? Here is the user click function: ```$(document).on('click', 'path[data-availability="Available"]', function () {...}```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the variable global. Define it outside the function:

```js
var path_str;
$(document).on('click', 'path[data-availability="Available"]', function () {
   path_str = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(this);
   get_data_mapping_for_id(this); //see below for this code
});
```